# Robolectric testing gridview onclick starting new activity

Tags: java, android, gridview, robolectric

I got stuck in making the test that checks if next Activity is started but using gridview on the click. It means that if one adaper is clicked, it will start new Activity (DetailActivity). I'm providing the gridview adapter that collects the data by list.

Here's the full code :

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayDetailActivityWhenAdapterClicked() throws Exception{
    List<ImageNode> nodes = new ArrayList<ImageNode>();
    ImageNode node = new ImageNode();
    node.setId(36597698);
    node.setContributorId("halfpoint");
    node.setFileName("halfpoint150200457");
    node.setFolder("halfpoint1502");
    node.setDescription("halfpoint1502");
    node.setMediaType("halfpoint1502");
    node.setUrlThumb(URLHelper.buildThumbUrl(
            node.getId(),
            node.getContributorId(),
            node.getFolder(),
            node.getFileName(),
            node.getDescription()));
    node.setUrlFullSize(URLHelper.buildFullSizeUrl(node.getUrlThumb()));
    nodes.add(node);
    DetailLikeBoxAdapter mAdapter = new DetailLikeBoxAdapter(activity, nodes);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) activity.findViewById(R.id.likebox_gridview);
    View itemView = mAdapter.getView(0, null, gridView);
    gridView.performItemClick(itemView, 0, mAdapter.getItemId(0));
    Intent startedIntent = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
    startedIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.DETAIL_IMAGE_KEY, node.getId());
    startedIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.DETAIL_IMAGE_POS, 0);
    startedIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.DETAIL_IMAGE_URLFULLSIZES,node.getUrlFullSize() );
    startedIntent.putExtra(CommonConstants.IS_BUILD_CATEGORY, false);// get intent of next activity on stack
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);            // create shadow intent which starts next activity
    assertEquals(DetailActivity.class.getName(), shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName()); // compare shadow intent w/ desired next activity
}
```

The error is java.lang.NullpointerException.

any ideas would be appriciated. Thank You.

Comment: You show us about 30 lines and your app will have many more lines. Where and why get you NullpointerException

Comment: I think NPE happens when performing click. Since `mAdapter` is not set to `GridView`. Several comments about your test - you should start mocking library to avoid a lot of setup code in test, yous should not put extra in intent in your test but should check in test that your class under test is setting up intent correctly

Comment: Wow! I think @EugenMartynov is right! I forget to write down `gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After having a bad time because of this case, I've successfully make the test working. Credit to @Eugen Martynov.

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayDetailActivityWhenAdapterClicked() throws Exception{
    List<ImageNode> nodes = new ArrayList<ImageNode>();
    ImageNode node = new ImageNode();
    node.setId(36597698);
    node.setContributorId("halfpoint");
    node.setFileName("halfpoint150200457");
    node.setFolder("halfpoint1502");
    node.setDescription("halfpoint1502");
    node.setMediaType("halfpoint1502");
    node.setUrlThumb(URLHelper.buildThumbUrl(
            node.getId(),
            node.getContributorId(),
            node.getFolder(),
            node.getFileName(),
            node.getDescription()));
    node.setUrlFullSize(URLHelper.buildFullSizeUrl(node.getUrlThumb()));
    nodes.add(node);
    DetailLikeBoxAdapter mAdapter = new DetailLikeBoxAdapter(activity, nodes);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) activity.findViewById(R.id.likebox_gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    View itemView = mAdapter.getView(0, null, gridView);
    gridView.performItemClick(itemView, 0, mAdapter.getItemId(0));
    Intent startedIntent = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);            // create shadow intent which starts next activity
    System.out.println(DetailActivity.class.getName()+" "+shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName() );
    assertEquals(DetailActivity.class.getName(), shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName()); // compare shadow intent w/ desired next activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for RoboElectric 3.1.2

```
loginButton.callOnClick();

Intent startedIntent = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);
assertEquals(NextActivity.class.getName(), shadowIntent.getIntentClass());
```